# Programming 3D motion

Tags: java, 3d

I'm trying to write code in Java to move a ship using two angles: one on the xy plane and one on the xz plane.  What I want is code that will do the following:

- If the xy and xz angles are 0, move along the positive x-axis
- If the xy angle is 90 and the xz angle is 0, move along the positive y-axis
- If the xy angle is 0 and the xz angle is 90, move along the positive z-axis

Here's what I have:

```
xyAngle = Math.toRadians(xyCourse);
xzAngle = Math.toRadians(xzCourse);
double deltaX = Math.cos(xyAngle) * Math.sin(xzAngle);
double deltaY = Math.sin(xyAngle) * Math.cos(xzAngle);
double deltaZ = Math.cos(xzAngle);

System.out.println(String.format("xyAngle = %.4f, xzAngle = %.4f", xyAngle, xzAngle));
System.out.println("xyAngle info: sin = " + Math.sin(xyAngle) + ", cos = " + Math.cos(xyAngle));
System.out.println("xzAngle info: sin = " + Math.sin(xzAngle) + ", cos = " + Math.cos(xzAngle));
System.out.println(String.format("deltaX = %.2f, deltaY = %.2f, deltaZ = %.2f", deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ));
for (int i = 0; i <= distance; i++) {
    System.out.println("Coordinates: " + String.format("(%.2f, %.2f, %.2f)", xCoordinate, yCoordinate, zCoordinate));
    xCoordinate += deltaX;
    yCoordinate += deltaY;
    zCoordinate += deltaZ;
}
```

I can't seem to get this to work.  Anyone have any hints?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Please add more details.

Comment: I was getting results like this:
    Enter xy angle: 0
    Enter xz angle: 0
    deltaX = 0.00, deltaY = 0.00, deltaZ = 1.00

    Enter xy angle: 90
    Enter xz angle: 0
    deltaX = 0.00, deltaY = 1.00, deltaZ = 1.00

    Enter xy angle: 0
    Enter xz angle: 90
    deltaX = 1.00, deltaY = 0.00, deltaZ = 0.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Math.cos` and `Math.sin`, I think what you want can be done quite easily?

**Code:**

```
public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double [] xyAngles = {0.0, 90.0, 0.0, 45.0};
        double [] xzAngles = {0.0, 0.0, 90.0, 45.0};

        for(int i = 0; i < xyAngles.length; i++)
        {
            double xyAngleRad = Math.toRadians(xyAngles[i]);
            double xzAngleRad = Math.toRadians(xzAngles[i]);

            // To fulfill the 3 conditions mentioned
            double deltaX = Math.cos(xyAngleRad) * Math.cos(xzAngleRad);
            double deltaY = Math.sin(xyAngleRad) * Math.cos(xzAngleRad);
            double deltaZ = Math.cos(xyAngleRad) * Math.sin(xzAngleRad);

            System.out.printf("XY Angle: %4.2f, XZ Angle: %4.2f%n",
                    xyAngles[i], xzAngles[i]);
            System.out.printf("dX: %4.2f, dY: %4.2f, dZ: %4.2f%n%n",
                    deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ);
        }
    }
}
```

Did some testing with your mentioned values, as well as an additional case where the XY and XZ angles are both 45 degrees.
**Output:**

```
XY Angle: 0.00, XZ Angle: 0.00
dX: 1.00, dY: 0.00, dZ: 0.00

XY Angle: 90.00, XZ Angle: 0.00
dX: 0.00, dY: 1.00, dZ: 0.00

XY Angle: 0.00, XZ Angle: 90.00
dX: 0.00, dY: 0.00, dZ: 1.00

XY Angle: 45.00, XZ Angle: 45.00
dX: 0.50, dY: 0.50, dZ: 0.50
```

As shown from output,

- If the xy and xz angles are 0, dX is 1 (moving along +ve x-axis)
- If the xy angle is 90 and xz angle is 0, dY is 1 (moving along +ve y-axis)
- If the xy angle is 0 and xz angle is 90, dZ is 1 (moving along +ve z-axis)
- If the xy and xz angles are 45, dX dY dZ are all 0.5 (moving along all 3 axis?)

Comment: Sheesh, all this time and I was using incorrect calculations.  Thanks for the answer!